# How to overwrite event handler for 'click' event in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to overwrite event handler for click event. This is the event handler I have attached initially.

```
document.querySelector("[data-id='start-btn']")
            .addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
                //some code
            });
```

Again after some condition, I want to over write this handler and attach new for 'click' event.

```
 //removing
 document.querySelector("[data-id='start-btn']")
    .removeEventListener("click", function (evt) {
            //some code
        }, false);

  //attaching new
  document.querySelector("[data-id='start-btn']")
    .addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
            //code
        });
```

But still it is    executing the previous event handler.I have used removeEventListener(but I guess, its not working).

Guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: You are passing different functions to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`. That can't work.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to remove a handler added with `addEventListener` is to use `removeEventListener` with exactly the same arguments. That means you'll need a reference to the original function:

```
var handler = function (evt) {
    //some code
};
document.querySelector("[data-id='start-btn']").addEventListener("click", handler);
```

then to remove

```
document.querySelector("[data-id='start-btn']").removeEventListener("click", handler);
```

Answer (score 4):

`removeEventListener` makes sense really only when using function **references** rather than passing an entire function **body** to both it and `addEventListener`, which would potentially mean mass duplication of code (and, as you've found, doesn't work anyway.)

So, prepare a reference to your function:

```
function my_func() { /* code */ }
```

And pass it as the handler argument to `add/removeEventListener`

```
document.querySelector('query').addEventListener('click', my_func);
document.querySelector('query').removeEventListener('click', my_func);
```

There is an easier way that utilises an older coding standard. If you specifically want only one event handler for a given type and element, you can use the DOM-zero `onclick`.

```
document.querySelector('query').onClick = my_func;
document.querySelector('query').onClick = my_func2; /* my_func() will no longer fire */
```

Answer (score 4):

As you can see from some other answers, removing an event listener can be kind of a nightmare. Thankfully in certain circumstances there is an easier way: add another event listener that fires earlier and cancels out the rest.

In my case there was a `click` event handler I wanted to override and I was able to add another event handler with `useCapture=true` (among other things) to override it.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click',function (e) {
  if (e.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == 'regular') {
    e.target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div>One we do <strong>not want</strong></div>');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
document.body.addEventListener('click',function (e) {
  if (e.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == 'fixed') {//or any event or other pre-/evaluations/conditions here
    e.target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div>One we <strong>do want</strong></div>');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
  //document.querySelector('.somethingelse').click();//etc.
},true);
```

```html
<div><a href="#">Regular</a></div>
<div><a href="#">Fixed</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was building a chrome extension and for some reason `removeEventListener` was not working as expected. The solution I came up with was to use the [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method.
The documentation says

> Cloning a node copies all of its attributes and their values,
> including intrinsic (inline) listeners. It does not copy event
> listeners added using addEventListener() or those assigned to element
> properties.

What I did was created a clone for my actual element and replaced it with the cloned one. This removes all event listeners from the element. A simple example will be like

```
let newClonedElem = myActualElem.cloneNode(true);
myActualElem.parentNode.replaceChild(newClonedElem, myActualElem);
```